# Calculate unsystematic-risk of a firm in a regression with SD or R2?

Tags: risk

i'm studying for a finance exam and i can't answer this question. 
It is asking me to calculate the unsystematic risk of firm A and i have the following information:

Return firm A: 0,1% + 1,2Returnstockexchange

R² = 0,15

SD of regression = 0,38

Risk free rate = 5%

Market rate = 8%

I know that the SD is the total risk of the firm A, but how can i find the unsystematic risk from this?

Some post in the internet says that the Unsystematic risk is (1-R²) but i coudn't find anything solid about this subject, does someone here can answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to give you the answer directly (since this is your homework), but as a hint:
Y = a + bX + epsilon

variance_Y = b^2 variance_X + variance_epsilon, under the assumption that X and epsilon are independent. The variance of epsilon is what you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer. This isn't actually a homework, but a question that is likely to appear in my admission test.

That said, you mean that the unsystematic-risk (the portion unexplained from the regression) is the variance of the error? 

Since the question give me only the SD of the regression, does that mean that this is the SD of the error and the variance of the error then would be (0,38²)?

Do you have any thoughts in the (1-R²) for the unsystematic error too?

Sorry to bother, this questions is extremely important to me!

Comment: regarding (1-R^2): please note that $R^2 = cov(R_m, R_i)/(\sigma_m \sigma_i)$. Thus the relation between $R^2$ and B is given by: $B = cov(R_m, R_i) / \sigma_m ^2 = R^2 *\frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_m}$. So (1-R^2) = $1 - \frac{\sigma_m^2 B^2}{\sigma_i ^2}$. simplifying results into $(1-R^2) = \frac{(\sigma_\epsilon)^2}{(\sigma_m)^2}$. Where $\sigma_\epsilon$ is the residual risk. So, asuming i did not mess up my maths it looks like (1-R^2) gives you the ratio between residual risk and market risk (squared)

Comment: Assuming that you are given the value of R2, and assuming you know the variance of the market portfolio, you can isolate the residual risk $\sigma_\epsilon$. (The next link gives you the same result, but derives it in a different way http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2011/11/correlation-and-r-squared/)

Comment: You are helping me a lot, you seen to be very good at econometrics.
So it seens i can't find it with R² since i don't have the variance of the market.
About you first answer,i have the variance of X (0,38²), but how can i go about finding the variance of Y if i don't have access to the data used to estimate this regression? I only have the information given in the exercise.
My unsystematic would be => Var epsilon = variance_Y/(1.2² x 0,38²) going about your formula, can you give me another tip if its possible to get to the Variance_Y in this exercise?

Comment: Hey man, its me again, i'm reading a lot of different stuff here since i coudn't find the answer with your explanation (i only have the information in this post, no data to find the variance of Y)
I have 2 theories now to find the unsystematic risk:
1 - Since this is a 1 stock portfolio, the SD of Beta (0,38) gives me the total risk, so the unsystematic risk would be 0,38 - market risk. (But i don't know how to find market risk)
2 - If the Beta (1.0) is the market risk, and the beta of firm is 1.2, i have 20% more risk than the market, and this 20% is the Unsyst.risk.
What do you think?

Comment: Actually Unsystematic risk (firm risk) would be 20% from 38% (total risk) = 7,6%
So: Total risk = 38%, unsystematic risk = 7,6% and market risk = 30,4%. Does it make sense or i'm confusing some concepts here?

Comment: No. the beta of 1.2 gives you the systematic component of your risk. So the (1.2-1)=0.2 has nothing to do with your idiosyncratic risk.

Comment: just use the formulas as discussed above. We are stuck because the definitions of what you wrote are unclear: "SD of regression = 0,38" and
"Market rate = 8%". What do you mean with SD of regression? if SD of regression is the standard deviation of $\epsilon$ then you are done. That is the idiosyncratic risk. If you ment to say it is the total vol of the stock, the you only have to deduct the systematic component and you are done. I am not sure with what "market rate =8%" means. Do you mean the market RISK is 8%? or do you mean E(Rm) =8%?

Comment: Thanks for the patience with me, i'm studying by myself and isn't easy.
The SD is actually the SD of Beta, the vol. of the stock i guess. This SD isn't my total risk (market risk + unsystematic risk)? So what can i do with it to go for my unsystematic?
And market rate = 8% is actually the market return, not the market risk.

Comment: What do you mean with market rate? do you mean E(R_m) - rf? please be precise. Also when you say standard deviation of Beta, do you mean the standard deviation of the OLS estimator? As discused in the link below? Perhaps easier if you just post screenshot of the book. or tell me title, edition and page of book. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85943/how-to-derive-the-standard-error-of-linear-regression-coefficient

Comment: This question isn't from a book, its from a old test that i'm studying.
Yes, market return is the ERm as in the CAPM formula: ERi = Rf + (B x (ERm - ERf). And the SD of Beta is indeed the SD of the OLS estimator in the regression, in this regression the only coefficients estimated are the intercept  (0,1) and the angular (1,2), the angular have a SD of 0,38. If i had the data from the regression i could calculate the variance of the error (epsilon) and it would be my unsystematic like you said, but i don't have this information, only the information in this post.

Comment: I was thinking here, you gave me this interpretation for R²: (1−R2)=(σϵ)^2/(σm)²

I have R², and σm could be the SD of the beta estimated? (Since the beta is the systematic component of the risk..)

In that case > (1-0,15) = (σϵ)^2 / (0,38)², solving for (σϵ) = 0,3503, so my unsystematic error would be 35,02%?

Comment: The variance of the estimator is given by $var \hat{B}  = (\sigma_\epsilon)^2 (R_m ' R_m)$. So the SD of the Beta is linked to the residual risk that you need. But I am not sure how to solve it. looks like some piece of information is missing. So. in short: i don't know how to get the right answer, looks like some info is missing. Sorry mate. But i'm sure there are smarter people than me on this site that can help you more. For more info on variance of estimator see: http://www.ucs.mun.ca/~rmartinezesp/ECON4550web/OLSMATRIXpart2.pdf

Comment: That's ok, you already helped me a lot. Maybe the correct answer is just theorical, that the unsystematic risk is the SD of the error of the regression and that's it since it can't be found without the data.
Thanks a lot!